# Magento 1.9: How to get the appropriate products attributes details?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, view

I just display my attributes on the PLP page, but the attributes duplicates or mismatch, actually I am using **$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();** for getting appropriate attributes, but my attributes duplicates.

[image]

Instead of using this -> **$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();** what is the best way to get products attributes.

complete code : https://justpaste.it/290fr   Applied on list.phtml page.